# for...in loop through array of objects returns 'Cannot read property of undefined'

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I need to recursively navigate through a tree of objects until I find the matching element and push some data into it. Here's a simplified example of my structure:

```
post.comments = [
    {
        _id: a,
        content: 'Foo',
        replies: [
            {
                _id: aa,
                content: 'Foobar',
                replies: [
                    {
                        _id: aaa,
                        content: 'Foobarbaz',
                        replies: [...]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: ab,
                content: 'Barfoo',
                replies: [...]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: b,
        content: 'Bar',
        replies: [...]
    },
    {
        _id: c,
        content: 'Bar',
        replies: [...]
    },
    ...
]
```

The replies can be nested infinitely, in theory.

And here's my recursive function:

```
function findNode(comments, id, data) {
    for (let key in comments) {
        currentNode = comments[key]
        if (currentNode._id.equals(id)) {
            currentNode.replies.push(data)
            break;
        } else {
            if (currentNode.replies.length) {
                findNode(currentNode.replies, id, data)
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

findNode(post.comments, id, comment)
```

This function appears to only read through the child nodes of the first comment object, then exits with 'Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined' when it reaches a node without children (but I presumed that the `continue;` should pull it out of that branch of the tree?)

What is it I'm not getting about for loops and recursion?

**EDIT**: Sorry! `string.equals(id)` comes from Mongoose - it's equivalent to `string == id` for the puropses of this example array.

Comment: You need to declare `currentNode` with `let` or `var` or else it's global.

Comment: why you can not use lodash or _?

Comment: Where is String.equals defined?  Did you mean `if (currentNode._id == id)` ?

Comment: where is the `.equals` method coming from? A vanilla comparison in JavaScript looks like `comments.id === id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `currentNode.replies.length` if `currentNode.replies` is undefined. You should check if `currentNode.replies` is not `null`, would go somewhat like this:

`if (currentNode.replies && currentNode.replies.length) { ...`

EDIT: same goes for `currentNode._id`, check if it is not `null` before calling `currentNode._id.equals`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the original problem - but now I'm getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and I don't understand why! I think I'm covering all the cases??